# Force decoding of Play2's play.api.libs.ws.Response to UTF-8 in Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, utf8-decode

When I fetch content from the site http://dilbert.com, it gives me an invalid encoding: utf-8lias. No such encoding of course exists, but I cannot impact what the site tells me.

As a result of this, the play.api.libs.ws.Response object throws an UnsupportedEncodingException:

> [error] application - Error: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException:
>   utf-8lias

Of course even if the encoding given by the site is clearly faulty, the content is in UTF-8.

Can I somehow force the Scala WS Response to decode the response as UTF-8 anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution (hence not marking it as such), but I switched to the scalaj-http library instead, which doesn't seem to have issues reading http://dilbert.com.

https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http

I hope Play's HTTP library gets fixed, though.